# Laravel Homestead Site does not update

Tags: php, laravel

I am running homestead and laravel 5.5
The virtualbox homestead-7 is running and my laravel local page loading.
When I make changes to any kind of code in my website, my view does not update. But the link is correctly set to my local website.

**Homestead.yaml**

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Documents/Development/Medifaktor/MFS
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/MFS

sites:
    - map: local.medifaktor
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/MFS/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 93000
#       to: 9300
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

For example: I changed the title tag in this page, but when I refresh my locally hosted website, nothing changes in the view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.16.1/axios.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{!! asset('css/vendor.css') !!}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{!! asset('css/app.css') !!}" />
</head>

<body class="gray-bg">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Main view  -->
        @yield('content')

    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.0/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="{!! asset('js/app.js') !!}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{!! asset('js/main.js') !!}" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open the file where the folder maps to, I see the changes. When I hit refresh in the browser, nothing happens. The VM is running and shows no error.

I installed:

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead
cd Homestead
git checkout v6.5.0
bash init.sh
vagrant up
```

Something i noticed: in the past I used homestead up as a command. all homestead commands do not exist anymore. Therefore I used vagrant up in the Homestead folder. The VM is running, but still no changes are seen.

The VM points to the correct folder:
[image]

I then changed the title to "Test1"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test1</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.16.1/axios.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{!! asset('css/vendor.css') !!}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{!! asset('css/app.css') !!}" />
</head>

<body class="gray-bg">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Main view  -->
        @yield('content')

    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.0/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="{!! asset('js/app.js') !!}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{!! asset('js/main.js') !!}" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and I see in the source folder the change. Refreshing, does not change anything.

[image]

The web.php:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'local.medifaktor', 'namespace' => 'MFS'], function() {

    // ADMINISTRATION
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'admin'], function() {
        Route::get('/dashboard', 'MFSAdminController@dashboard')->name('admin.dashboard'); //->middleware('role:superadministrator|administrator|supervisor');
    });

    // INCIDENTS
    Route::get('/', 'Incidents\MFSIncidentController@index');
    Route::get('/incidents', 'Incidents\MFSIncidentController@incidents')->name("home");

    // MFUSERS
    Route::get('/register', 'Authentication\MFSAuthenticationController@register');
    Route::get('/login', 'Authentication\MFSAuthenticationController@login');

// Route::get('/incidents/{incidents}', 'MFS\PagesController@incidents');

// GIS
    Route::get('/gis', 'MFS\PagesController@gis')->name("minor");

});
```

Comment: I don't know about the environment homestead , but curious to know what it does. and do you use Composer?

Comment: Yes, I do use composer. All seems to work well, except for my VM setup

Comment: have you tried `php artisan cache:clear` ?

Comment: Can you try vagrant reload --provision ?

Comment: yep just tried cache:clear

Comment: Tried that too @Nartub no effect